# how to adjust my windows sound volume to 30 using cmd promt

Tags: windows, windows-8

I want to adjust my windows sound volume to 30 using cmd prompt without using mouse or keyboard.

My intention is to create a bat file and once I plugin my headset Iwill change my system volume using the bat file.

Answer (score 0):

There is a freeware utility that will do thatr, NirCmd. You can download it [here](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html).

To set the system volume just type:

```
nircmd.exe setsysvolume 65535
```

Since the volume varies from 0 to 65535, for a volume of about 30% (out of 100), you will type:

```
nircmd.exe setsysvolume 19661
```